# Merging tables in Excel

Tags: excel, merge

I have the following two tables in Excel:

```
Table 1:
||Component|Column 1|Column2||
|Comp1|V12|V12|
|Comp2|V21|V21|

Table 2:
||Component|Column 3|Column 4||
|Comp1|X12|X12|
|Comp2|X21|X22|
|Comp3|X31|X32|
|Comp4|X41|X42|
```

that I am looking to merge/combine into one, keeping all the columns from both tables intact:

```
Merge Result
||Component|Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|Column 4||
|Comp1|V12|V12|X12|X12|
|Comp2|V21|V22|X21|X22|
|Comp3|||X31|X32|
|Comp4|||X41|X42|
```

Comment: Excel 2010, unfortunately.

Comment: is it a one off of a recurring task?

Comment: I do have to generate the report daily.